# Stripe having trouble extracting the json card id

Tags: stripe-payments

With Stripe php I am creating a new source with code below.

- then when I show $response_all it looks like good json like:

{id: "card_xxxxxxxxxx", object: "card", address_city: null, address_country: null, address_line1: null, …} etc.......

however when I try to extract just the id only using
$response_id = $response.id;

then the json has a TEXT prefix like
"Stripe\Card JSON: {
"id": "card_xxxxxxxxxx", etc

Q: How Can I extract the Card id without getting the text prefix?

```
$stripe_customer = $_POST['stripe_customer'];


$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
'sk_test_xxxxxxxxx'
);

$response = $stripe->customers->createSource(
$stripe_customer,
['source' => $token]
); 


$response_all =  $response;

$response_id = $response.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use arrow notation in PHP to get object properties:

```
$response_id = $response->id
```

`.` is string concatenation in PHP, which means that in your code you probably saw the whole JSON object printed with the string `id` added to the end.